# How to handle a pop-up window when that shows up at uncertain time?

Tags: java, selenium, popup, automated-tests, alert

I am trying to automate test cases. It's difficult since the pop message appears at uncertain time as a result the test case fails. Sometimes pop-up appears without a  click and other times it is 5-6 clicks before the pop-up appears. I can't locate the pop-up there is no id or XPath.

Comment: Is the popup a system dialogue like a print window or is it a web element? I've used the AutoIT library to handle weird popups and windows that selenium can't interact with.

Answer (score 0):

If popup is windows based then use AutoIT library.
If it is web popup then you can handle it by following code

```
Set<String> set =  driver.getWindowHandles();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(set);

// store your main window handle in variable
String mainWindow = list.get(0);

// To close all unwanted popup
for(int i =1; i <list.size(); i++)
{
    String unwantedPopup = list.get(i);
    driver.switchTo().window(unwantedPopup);
    driver.close();
}

// Switch back to your main window
driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
```

Comment: Thank you Akash. However the code doesn't work, it has syntax error. i have not been able to figure out. I forgot to mention it's a modal dialog box. I have  also tried driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
        driver.close(); Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert().dismiss();.The modal dialog box appears when I use  Thread.sleep(8000). I am unable to close the box I am running the code on chrome on mac I also also tried bunch of other one but no help.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that works for me.

```
    Thread.sleep(5000); //wait for the modal message to appear
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```